# Curve Modifier- not starting at beginning

Tags: curve-modifier

why is it, that the object does not start at the very beginning of the curve?
It starts randomly at some point but still is affected by the curve-origin - without any clear logic behind it..

in the first picture the curve-origin is at the first vertex

in the second the curve-origin is at the middle of the gemoetry

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's simpler to have both the 2 objects origin at their geometry, and have both the 2 objects at the same location, then when you'll give your object the Curve modifier the object origin (not the object tip) will jump to the beginning of the curve. If you want to make it begin at it's tip, move it along X

Comment: The problem here seems to be the origin of the object which should follow the curve, at least that's the impression I get. Can you show a screenshot of the object with the modifiers turned off? Anyway, as @moonboots said, their origins should be in the same location

Answer (score 1):

**How the *Curve* modifier works**

Hopefully this is not too confusing - it's just a quick overview of the problems with placing objects correctly to deform along a curve. Maybe someone might be able to explain it better. For a basic understanding I intentionally left out more complicated things like different rotations or scale of the objects.

I use a simple geometry like a long cuboid which is subdivided very often in X direction (because it's the default deformation axis when adding the *Curve* modifier), so it can follow the curve more smoothly. I take a simple Bézier curve as the target.

In the first example, both objects have their origin in the same location, furthermore the curve's first vertex is placed at the origin and the cuboid has its origin to the left so that all geometry is lying in +X direction.

[image: simple setup]

If I now put the *Curve* modifier on the cuboid and select the Bézier curve, it works pretty much as expected: the cuboid gets deformed along its X, starting at the beginning of the curve.

[image: simple deform]

A different thing happens if the geometry of the cuboid is centered around the origin like in the following example:

[image: offset geometry]

Although the curve and cuboid still have their origins in the same location, only the right side of the cuboid gets deformed. Everything left of the origin (with X < 0) is just aligned in the direction of the curve's first vertex tangent.

[image: partly undeformed]

Now when the origin in the center of the cuboid means that it is extended to the left or "before" the curve's origin, this might seem like extending the curve in this direction might help. So let's say I add a vertex to the curve on the left side:

[image: new vertex]

But instead of just having the cuboid deform in both directions it has moved further down the curve to the left. And here is the reason: **Are both objects with their origins in the same location, the deformation starts with the object's geometry offset from its origin to the first vertex of the curve.**

[image: cuboid offset from curve origin]

So the simplest thing to deform an object exactly along the curve is moving them both to the same location, with the deforming object's geometry "beginning" at the origin, not centered.

These were all examples where cuboid and curve are in the same location. What happens if they are not? In the next example, the cuboid is moved 3 m in +Y direction:

[image: origin offset]

The cuboid is now deformed along the curve with an offset of 3 m perpendicular to the curve's tangent (because +Y is to the "left" of the X deformation axis). The same thing would happen if you moved the cuboid's mesh in +Y direction in *Edit Mode* and leave the origin where the curve is.

[image: perpendicular deformation offset]